# Dataframe returning empty after assignment of values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Essentially, I would like to add values to certain columns in an empty DataFrame with defined columns, but when I run the code, I get.

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [AP, AV]
Index: []
```

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['AP', 'AV'])  
df['AP'] = propName 
df['AV'] = propVal
```

I think this could be a simple fix, but I've tried some different solutions to no avail. I've tried adding the values to an existing dataframe I have, and it works when I do that, but would like to have these values in a new, separate structure.

Thank you,

Comment: What are `propname` and `propval`?

Comment: @G.Anderson 

PropName and propVal are values pulled from a DataFrame I'm reading in from Excel called propData:

        propName = propData.iloc[1, 0]
        idx = propData.index[propData[0] == 'Total Unleveraged Present Value'].tolist()[0]
        propVal = propData.iloc[idx, 1]

Comment: Updated my message with a detailed description of the reason.

Answer (score 2):

It's the lack of an index.
If you create an empty dataframe with an index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index = [5])
```

Output

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [5]
```

Then when you set the value, it will be set.

```
df[5] = 12345
```

Output

```
       5
5  12345
```

You can also create an empty dataframe. And when setting a column with a value, pass the value in the list. The index will be automatically set.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['qwe'] = [777]
```

Output

```
   qwe
0  777
```

Comment: I need to define the DataFrame to use globally. propName and propValue are local variables used within a for-loop. Any tips?

Comment: Initialize with some specific values, and then replace them with the necessary ones.
If you have a pre-known number of values for columns?

Comment: Thanks, that works! Can you explain why your code works, but mine didn't? New to this and want to learn.

Comment: As far as I understand, an empty dataframe has no) [index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html)

Comment: Understood, but I thought me assigning a value would no longer make the dataframe empty? For example, I initialize another empty dataframe, and then populate that dataframe with data from yet another dataframe, and that works with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Assign propName and propValue to dictionary:

```
dict = {}
dict[propName] = propValue
```

Then, push to empty DataFrame, df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['AP'] = dict.keys()
df['AV'] = dict.values()
```

Probably not the most elegant solution, but works great for me.