# for loop with if statement to go through dataframe to check of column values startswith a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement, startswith

I have a shapefile that I am bringing in with geopandas. I do not need all the rows, just certain rows that start with 01, 02, and 03 for the route_id. I use a for loop and an if statement to try to append the data I want to an empty dataframe. Below is the sample Data:

| ROUTE_ID | FROM_MEASU | TO_MEASURE | STREET_PRE | BASE_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0100006595050034-D | 5.799725 | 9.678965 |  | 215th |
| 0200006595050034-D | 0 | 9.678965 | ST | 220th |
| 0300006595050034-D | 5.799725 | 9.678965 |  | 215th |
| 0400006595050034-D | 0 | 9.678965 | ST | 220th |

my code is as follows:

```
mnlrshwy = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ROUTE_ID','FROM_MEASU','TO_MEASURE','STREET_PRE',
                                 'BASE_NAME'])
for x in mnlrs['ROUTE_ID']:
    if x.startswith(('01','02','03')) is True:
        mnlrshwy = x.append(mnlrs,ignore_index = True)
```

I get a concatenation error which I don't understand why I would get something like that.
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I think it does, but i get: ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values. So, there must be blank cells in that column somewhere.

Comment: I used this code to solve this issue: 
mnlrs=mnlrs[mnlrs['ROUTE_ID'].notna()]

Answer (score 1):

If you use pandas, you won't need a for loop.

```
df[df['ROUTE_ID'].str.contains("^0(1|2|3)", regex=True, na=False)]
```

Comment: Much simpler solution, +1. Also worth noting, though, could also use `Series.str.startswith()` instead of `contains()` to make the code a bit more self-documenting

Comment: I ended up using this: 
routes = ['01','02','03']
mnlrshwy=mnlrs[mnlrs.ROUTE_ID.str.startswith(tuple(routes))]

Answer (score 0):

perform type check at each stage, or convert it into string then append it to your data frame.

Answer (score 0):

df Output

```
             ROUTE_ID  FROM_MEASU  TO_MEASURE STREET_PRE BASE_NAME
0  0100006595050034-D    5.799725    9.678965        NaN     215th
1  0200006595050034-D    0.000000    9.678965         ST     220th
2  0300006595050034-D    5.799725    9.678965        NaN     215th
3  0400006595050034-D    0.000000    9.678965         ST     220th
```

Above is the data of your dataframe.

```
mnlrshwy = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ROUTE_ID', 'FROM_MEASU', 'TO_MEASURE', 'STREET_PRE',
                                 'BASE_NAME'], index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
for x in range(0, len(df['ROUTE_ID'])):
    if df.loc[x, 'ROUTE_ID'].startswith(('01', '02', '03')) is True:
        mnlrshwy.loc[x, :] = df.loc[x, 'ROUTE_ID']

print(mnlrshwy)
```

Output

```
             ROUTE_ID          FROM_MEASU          TO_MEASURE  \
0  0100006595050034-D  0100006595050034-D  0100006595050034-D   
1  0200006595050034-D  0200006595050034-D  0200006595050034-D   
2  0300006595050034-D  0300006595050034-D  0300006595050034-D   
3                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN   

           STREET_PRE           BASE_NAME  
0  0100006595050034-D  0100006595050034-D  
1  0200006595050034-D  0200006595050034-D  
2  0300006595050034-D  0300006595050034-D  
3                 NaN                 NaN
```

You get one value at each iteration. And if there are no indexes in an empty dataframe, then it will not be possible to assign a value. Unless you add a value in square brackets.  Here you can see about an empty [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71928612/dataframe-returning-empty-after-assignment-of-values/71929079#71929079)

I filled in on each iteration the rows of all columns. Using loc on the left is the indexes, on the right is the name of the column.